# MariaDB - order by with more selects

Tags: select, tags, mariadb

I have this SQL:

```
select * from `posts` 
where `posts`.`deleted_at` is null 
and `expire_at` >= '2017-03-26 21:23:42.000000' 
and (
select count(distinct tags.id) from `tags` 
inner join `post_tag` on `tags`.`id` = `post_tag`.`tag_id` 
where `post_tag`.`post_id` = `posts`.`id` 
and (`tags`.`tag` like 'PHP' or `tags`.`tag` like 'pop' or `tags`.`tag` like 'UI')
) >= 1
```

Is it possible order the results by number of tags in posts?
Maybe add there alias?

Any information can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert your correlated subquery into a join:

```
select p.*
from posts p
join (
    select pt.post_id,
        count(distinct t.id) as tag_count
    from tags t
    inner join post_tag pt on t.id = pt.tag_id
    where t.tag in ('PHP', 'pop', 'UI')
    group by pt.post_id
    ) pt on p.id = pt.post_id
where p.deleted_at is null
    and p.expire_at >= '2017-03-26 21:23:42.000000'
order by pt.tag_count desc;
```

Also, note that I changed the bunch of `like` and `or` to single `IN` because you are not matching any pattern i.e. there is no `%` in the string. So, better using single `IN` instead.

Also, if you have defined your table names, column names etc keeping keywords etc in mind, you shouldn't have the need to use the backticks. They make reading a query difficult.

Comment: I have like because of Laravel. The code is: `$this->posts($request)->whereHas('tags', function ($q) use ($tags) {
          $q->where(function ($q) use ($tags) {
            foreach ($tags as $tag) {
              $q->orWhere('tags.tag', 'like', $tag["tag"]);
            }
          })->select(DB::raw('count(distinct tags.id)'));
        })->paginate(perPage());`

Comment: @Maximi - Sorry? I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Laravel have query builder for the whole SQL. I think your SQL cannot be constructed by Laravel. But answer of course good. But no really solution for me now.

Comment: @Maximi - I am not an expert at Laravel. You can try to translate this into Laravel. If you can't, open a new question posting what you current sql and laravel try is.